# Could not run build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app iOS 17.1

Tags: flutter, xcode, macos

Could not run build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app on xxxxx
Try launching Xcode and selecting "Product Run" to fix the problem:
open ios/Runner.xcworkspace
Error launching application on my Device

Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0)
Flutter version 3.7.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would need more info to determine the cause of your issue
but you could try this if you haven't.

1. Make sure flutter and dart are up to date
2. Make sure command line tool for Xcode is updated
3. Run flutter clean
4. Update packages if need to
5. Run pod update and pod install